# My SSIS manifest does not allow deployment in the production environment

Tags: sql-server-2008, deployment, ssis

I have a existing DTSX package which I cannot deploy from within the package directory or from a network share.

When I double click or use a command line to deploy this update from a network share...

> dtsinstall C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Packages\myPackage\myPackage.ssisdeploymentmanifest

results in the following error:

> TITLE: Package Installation Wizard
>
> You need to specify the full path to a SSIS deployment manifest file.

When I try simply copying to my C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Packages\myPackage\ directory and double-clicking on the manifest file there, I get the following error:

> TITLE: Package Installation Wizard
>
> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Packages\myPackage\myPackage.dtsx' because it is being used by another process.

This is only slightly better, because the Package Installation Wizard launches, and then fails. I was able to get this done the Test environment. Both servers are Windows Server 2008 with SQL Server 2008, R2. My permissions vary slightly on the two servers, but I don't know the details yet.

Comment: Are you an administrator on the box you are tying to install you SSIS package to?

Comment: Do you have both SQL 2005 and SQL 2008 on the box you are tying to install you SSIS package to, or just SQL 2008?

Comment: I have elevated rights but I am apparently not an administrator. The sysadmin told me that I was a local administrator - we're both confused it seems. Interestingly, I was successful installing the package from My Documents. Please tell me why in an answer to receive full credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install this package when I navigated to the My Documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are running into UAC (User Account Control) on Windows 2008.

Possible solution: "Run As Administrator" the DTSINSTALL.EXE application (Package Installation Wizard).

For more info see [User Account Control Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28WS.10%29.aspx).